# Gcloud ml speech recognize - not returning national characters

Tags: google-speech-to-text-api

I am trying to use speech to text cloud library from google.
When I use this command on command line:

```
gcloud ml speech recognize-long-running test.wav --language-code=cs-CZ > output.txt
```

It returns readed text, but without national characters, in this case it returns:

```
{
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeResponse",
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.93263865,
          "transcript": "tento i ledvinkov? modul obsahuje d?le?itost Oliver Pro? je pro n?s d?le?it? abychom se ne zam??ovaly jen na to ?e mus?me dos?hnout sv? c?le ale jak jich dos?hnout zvl??t? v dob?ch zm?n a transformace mus?me neust?le vyhodnocovat zda zp?sob jak?m dnes d?l?me v?ci je st?le spr?vn?"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

where all national characters are replaced by ? character.

I was searching in api doc for speech to text, but it looks, there is no parameter to set returning characters set.
Does anyone know, how to get result with national characters?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your console cannot display UTF8

Comment: I dont think. Export from gcloud ml goes to file, which I open in notepad, but tried different text editors, where I try to change file encoding. But when I looked on file content in hexadecimal format, all questionmark characters has the same code, so I fear, this was returned from google cloud.

Comment: This is definitely not google cloud, it is cmd, redirect, utf8 problem, search these words or may be try to change system locale for non-unicode programs to Czech.